# Does facebook allow sharing text(not link)?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sharer

i've been struggling these last days to make my app share some text and make it as a status in facebook.First i've tried action SEND(the easy way), but i was just able to send links. So i used facebook SDK(4.1.0) and i was obliged to switch from eclipse to android studio to be able to apply facebook documentation.
Now after all this , i find out that even facebook sdk allows just sharing links , photos or video .

**So my question is** 
Does facebook allow sharing simple text(NOT LINK) and make it as a status programatically??
if yes, please tell me how ??
if no , why do i have apps(i the google play) that share the user's best result via facebook? how do they achieve it?

this is my code to share via facebook (it's the same as the documentation [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android))

```
share = (ShareButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sharebuttonnn);

ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
        .build();
share.setShareContent(content);
```

Comment: What is your use case for only sharing text?

Comment: If you post a message in the name of the user of your app, then that message has to be a 100% user generated, i.e. typed in by that user. You are explicitly not allowed to post a message that your app specifies for them.

Comment: @CBroe: even with open graph story??

Comment: @BellilMedSamouel: The story itself would be defined by the app, but if the user wants to include a message with their story post, yes, that has to be a 100% their own as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Facebook sdk for sharing text.Using facebook share builder sharing link is possible but sharing text is not possible.

Another alternative you can share text using native facebook app is installed on device otherwise you can show that facebook app is not installed on your device.

Comment: Can you provide a link please for "Facebook sdk for sharing text"??, i already installed a native facebook app on my device !!

Comment: Please check this link is it helpful or not.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android#sharedialog